# error : expected ';', '.' or ')' before '&' token in Code::Blocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

```
struct BinaryTree {
   struct BinaryTree * left;
   int data;
    struct BinaryTree * right;
} ;

typedef struct BinaryTree * IntPtr;

void Add( IntPtr & head, int data ) { // error
    scanf( "%d", &data );
    head = new IntPtr;
    head -> left = NULL;
    head -> data = data;
    head -> right = NULL;
} // Add()
```

why it displays " error : expected ';', '.' or ')' before '&' token ?

```
int main( )
{
    IntPtr head = NULL;
    int data = 0;
    Add( head, data );
} // main()
```

I don't understand why it is error . I use Code::Blocks for the first time.

Comment: `new IntPtr;`? Is this C++ or C?

Comment: @Eraklon Oops. I forgot to delete this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Add( IntPtr & head, ...

head = new IntPtr;
```

It seems C++, in C you cannot use the syntax like that. You can pass the pointer instead of using reference (do not forget to allocate the memory).

```
head -> left = NULL;
head -> data = data;
head -> right = NULL;
```

In C, you cannot use the space between variable and `->`. You have to eliminate the space as below:

```
head->left = NULL;
head->data = data;
head->right = NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
IntPtr & head
```

This syntax is not C. References only exist in C++. If you meant a pointer, then it's an asterisk, not an ampersand.

Comment: Thx. I change c into c++ environment